# how to delete files from an array after a check?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
path="/home/asdf"
dateminusoneday=$(date +%m --date='-1 month')
date=$(date +"%Y-$dateminusoneday-%d")


 list=$(find /home/asdf | grep -P '\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}' -o)
 listArray=($list)
         for i in "${listArray[@]}"
         do
         echo $i  
         if [[  $i < $date ]]; then
         echo "delete file"
         else
         echo "no need delete this file"  fi  done
```

I need to delete the smallest files that date. but I do not get it

What would be the most optimal way?

thanks all.

Comment: Show some input (what your files look like) and output (what files you want to delete) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I see that you are trying to delete files older than one month. If I am not mistaken and you can accept that (1 month)==(30 days) you can use such one-liner:

```
find "$path" -mtime +30 -delete
```

If you want exactly 1 mont (not 30 days) you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="/home/asdf"

number_of_days=$((($(date '+%s')-$(date -d '1 month ago' '+%s'))/86400))
find "$path" -mtime +$number_of_days -delete
```

Comment: This may fail/ It will fail on many special characters, like spaces in filenames and spaces in `$path` variable.

Comment: True. Thanks for the hint. I added quotes around $path.

Comment: @Szczerba That is not enough. You rely on word-splitting here `rm $(...)`. You should choose a different approach; for example `find ... -delete`.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it is ok now.